# How could i validate and save a value in checkbox from a form?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm doing a TODO List in Laravel 5.8, and one of my fields in my table for my tasks is **status**, which has boolean value. And i want when status is equals to **0 (uncheck)** it'd be TODO, and if is **equals to 1** it'd be Done (check).
The image below is my CRUD for tasks, and the third task in selected, because i entered that value (status = 1) from MySQL. But i want change that value editing it in my crud, but i can't do it from the Form.

[Task table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDmJj.png)

This is when i'm updating the task
[Updating task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSzVQ.png)

As I said before, if I check the last "parameter" it is not saved.

I have the next code for checkbox from my `edit.blade.php`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-check izquierda" >
        <label class="form-check-label">   
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="status" value="{{$task->status}} "{{$task->status==1 ? 'checked' : ''}}>
            <span class="form-check-sign" >
                <span class="check"></span>
            </span>
            <label for="">Done</label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And i have the following in my TaskController.php

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $task = Task::find($id);
    return view('user.tasks.edit',compact('task'));
}

public function update(Request $request,$id)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name'     => 'required',
        'notes'    => 'required',
        'schedule' => 'required',
        'status'   => '',
    ]);

    $task = Task::find($id);
    $task->name = $request->name;
    $task->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $task->notes = $request->notes;
    $task->schedule = $request->schedule;
    $task->status = $request->status; //false <- thats equals TODO (no done yet)
    // $task->user_id = User::find($id);

    $task->save();

    return redirect()->route('user.tasks.index')->with('successMsg','Taks sucessfully edited.');
}
```

So, what could i do? I researched about this, but i couldn't solve this until now. I will appreciate if you help me with this problem that i have. Thanks in advance

Comment: You have saved a status value in the database?

Comment: Yes i have that field on my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-check izquierda" >
        <label class="form-check-label">   
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="status" {{ $task->status ? 'checked=checked' : '' }}>
            <span class="form-check-sign" >
                <span class="check"></span>
            </span>
            <label for="">Done</label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

On your Controller

```
public function update(Request $request,$id)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name'     => 'required',
        'notes'    => 'required',
        'schedule' => 'required',
    ]);

    if (isset($request->status)) {
        $status = true;
    } else {
        $status = false;
    }

    $task = Task::find($id);
    $task->name = $request->name;
    $task->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $task->notes = $request->notes;
    $task->schedule = $request->schedule;
    $task->status = $status; 

    $task->save();

    return redirect()->route('user.tasks.index')->with('successMsg','Taks sucessfully edited.');
}
```

Comment: Nice, now it works good :) thanks for help me. Where can i find more info about this type of validation? I want to learn more about that. Thanks again :)

Comment: @JorgePerezDiaz To know more about validation rule you can check this source. [https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation]